# Find the temperature equation $T(x)$ when $T''(x)$ and initial values are given

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> We have a $50$ cm long metal rod where the left end and right end are kept at constant temperature, which are $25$ and $85$ degrees Celsius respectively. Assume that we choose the $x$-axis parallel to the metal rod such that $T(0)=25$ and $T(50)=85$. Experiments shows that $T(x)$ satisfies $T''(x)=0$.
> Find $T(x)$ for $x\in[0,50]$.

I tried to solve this by integral method but the final expression didn't satisfy the boundary condition for the rod.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T''(x)=0$ then $T(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$, which are uniquely determined by the initial conditions.

Comment: It is a $T''(x)$, which means that I have to integrate twice, not only once...

Comment: If $T''(x)=0$ then $T'(x)=a$ for some $a\in\Bbb{R}$, hence $T(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Aha, now it makes sense, thanks :D